# Docker/Compose: Let --add-host/extra_host point to other container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Web app setup, consisting of a reverse proxy (serving http) and the actual app behind it.

```yaml
services:
    proxy:
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - default
            - backend
        ports:
            - 80:80

    app:
        extra_hosts:
            - "api.myapp.com:127.0.0.1"
        networks:
            - backend
        expose:
            - 9000
```

It used to be one container, so in order to make HTTP API calls from the app to the app (without going through SSL termination), I simply added an extra_host to `compose.yml` pointing to `127.0.0.1` like in the example above.

In the new setup `api.myapp.com` is supposed to point to the proxy container’s IP.

It would be great, if docker compose supported something like this:

```yaml
extra_hosts:
     - "api.myapp.com:proxy"
```

But it doesn’t.

Oh, and I can’t simply make API calls to `http://proxy` instead of `http://api.myapp.com` because the app contains binaries not under my control.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out I may use links for this:

```yaml
app:
    links:
        - proxy:api.myapp.com
```

This works, but turns the dependency graph upside down. Normally, proxy depends on app. The link inverses this, so I had to remove `depends_on` from Proxy to avoid a circular dependency.

Hopefully, there’s a better solution for this.